# Any one knows about an issue with facebook live stream social plugin, and how to fix it?

Tags: xml, facebook

I'm haveing a weird problem with facebook live stream plugin, I'm working with a XML file and it no matter what i do, when i try to add the plugin from the facebook developer site it doesn't work.

I found on the internet an Iframe version of the plugin and it is working but the code that facebook produce doesn't work.

THe problem with the Iframe version is that, In my system, every customer creates his own site and i need a unique chat for each site, The Iframe don't has XID attribute that let you and a unique one, but the Iframe doesn't support it.

The one that doesn't work:

```
<div id="fb-root"><xsl:comment/></div><script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/en_US/all.js#appId={AppID}&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:live-stream width="200" height="300" always_post_to_friends="false"><xsl:comment/></fb:live-stream>
```

Code that Does work, but is not good for me:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/live_stream_box.php?app_id={AppID}&amp;width=315&amp;height=388&amp;via_url&amp;always_post_to_friends=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:315px; height:388px;" allowTransparency="true"><xsl:comment/></iframe>
```

Both are rapped in a div(each one in it's turn, not together ofcourse):

```
<div id="facebook_plug" class="facebook_plug"><xsl:comment/>
...
</div>
```

If any one has an idea it will help me very much,
Tnx,
Erez

Answer (score -2, accepted):

10X guys,

Fixed it. Facebook has some hidden attributes that needs to be added, and I had to put the script section in the head, and some XML comments in the div and fb and then every thing worked like a charm.

10x

Comment: Could you pleasssseeeee pleassseeee tell us how you fixed this !!!! Stack Overflow is about sharing information!